# The Simultaneity of Cause and Effect

Tags: philosophy, sunyata, causes, nichiren, cause-and-effect

> The conventional Buddhist view of causality is that the present
> negative and positive effects we see in our lives are a result of
> negative and positive causes that we created in the past. So in order
> to attain Buddhahood, which is the goal of Buddhist practice, it would
> take lifetimes of painstaking efforts to replace all the negative
> causes we’ve made with positive causes, while avoiding making
> additional negative causes. Based on this view, the possibility of
> attaining Buddhahood seems remote and almost impossible.
>
> In contrast, Nichiren Buddhism teaches that the law of cause and
> effect is simultaneous.

https://www.worldtribune.org/2017/11/cause-and-effect/

I side against it, which could even cover my slight antipathy toward Nichiren Buddhism.

If the effect depends on past causes, then doesn't the metaphor of a fire going out -- and going nowhere -- when the fuel runs out, only work when a cause can run out of effects, which, for me, hints at svabhava.

Does a cause running itself down only occur if it has svabhava? And what arguments are there for and against the law of cause and effect being simultaneous?

I have a "theory" that Nichiren Buddhism cannot help us in our "next live"; in deed, that mappo -- and Nichiren Buddhism -- condemns all to the Abrahamic hell, even as zen -- the monastic life -- may still be available. But I won't get into it.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional Standard 日蓮仏教/ Nichiren Buddhism at Minobu Yama c.1280AD is about refinement and being kindly and nice and is quite based on The Teachings of The Buddha, & Guidance of 日蓮/ Nichiren Daishi, His writings, and careful consideration of The Lotus Sutra. Nichiren Buddhism is about the present and future, yet doesnot discount the past, and Nichiren Daishi didn't discount the past: Nichiren Daishi instructed that past karma could be 'expunged' through observance of The Teachings in The Lotus Sutra, conceiveably in present Lifetimes.

The Organisation of the text cited in the question is fairly recent, and the text cited isnot Nichiren Daishi's Teachings; maybe the article suffered in translation, since 'simultaneous' wouldnot typically be understood as 'within one lifetime', or, maybe some places actually would intend to say what it says. Standard Traditional Nichiren Buddhism is based on Teachings of The Buddha, And Traditional Nichiren Buddhism doesnotsay cause & effect are simultaneous in that sense. Interesting citation and good question.